# How to capture BBC live stream with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have FFmpeg and I'd like to use it to capture live streams on BBC iPlayer.

Does anyone know the commands needed for this and how I can find the correct playlist?

Comment: First you neex to be in UK or use a British VPN but even with that I think it's not possible.

Comment: thank you @GabrielaGarcia yeah, i'm in the uk, just a pity that i can't do this.